# How to run python script in linux Executable shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, hudson, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

I Have a python script ready and I need to run using Hudson CI. I can see configure job having the only environment supported is an executable shell. How can I run a python script in the executable shell (Bash shell)? any idea or suggestions?

Comment: `python xxx.py`?

Answer (score 0):

python3

```
python3 file.py
```

python2

```
python file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious `python3 file.py` or `python file.py`, it is possible to make the python file executable on its own by introducing an appropriate shebang at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
...
(script follows here)
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
...
(script follows here)
```

Using these, your CI doesn't need to know that the script is written in python, in shell, in perl or whatever language it uses.